# Why does databinding VM after initializing Kendo grid work in Chrome and not IE?

Tags: kendo-ui, internet-explorer-9, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I setup a simple example in jsFiddle where I initialize a kendo grid and then bind a viewmodel. The data is populated in the grid for each row in Chrome but not in IE9.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="example">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Units</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-template="row-template" data-bind="source: products"></tbody>
</table>
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name">
        </td>
        <td>
            #: kendo.toString(get("price"), "C") #
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: unitsInStock"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    products: [{
        name: "Hampton Sofa",
        price: 989.99,
        unitsInStock: 39
    }, {
        name: "Perry Sofa",
        price: 559.99,
        unitsInStock: 17
    }, {
        name: "Donovan Sofa",
        price: 719.99,
        unitsInStock: 29
    }, {
        name: "Markus Sofa",
        price: 839.99,
        unitsInStock: 3
    }]
});

   $("#example table").kendoGrid();
   kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2XHN/1/

In my original example I use `data-role="grid"` on the table element but this code is clearer. If `$("#example table").kendoGrid();` is after `kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);` then it works in IE. If it is before then it does not work and no exceptions appear in the console. It works both ways in chrome.

I know that I could just set it up as the datasource for the grid as well. My preference is to use `data-role="grid"`, so that is why I care.

**So I have a work-around, but does anyone know why this doesn't work in IE9 but does in Chrome?**

*I would just open this as a bug with Telerik but when I go to their public issue tracker (http://www.telerik.com/support/pits.aspx) it comes up blank for me.*

Comment: One undesirable side effect of initializing the datagrid after databinding is that if you have checkboxes in the tbody trs then they will be removed but they stay if you databind after initializing the datagrid (in chrome of course).

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with the Kendo Grid. It was working with Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and IE10, but not IE9.

What I found out is the row-template had "invalid" HTML, in my case a `<table>` around the `<tr>`, which was tolerated by more modern browsers, but not by IE9.

I was getting no errors, just a sad empty grid.

So the advice is, check your row-template, because if there is something invalid, it will just not render content in the `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use data-row-template on the table and bind the data there as well rather than in the tbody:

See updated Fiddle working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kyeo7gaf/)

```
<div id="example">
<table data-row-template="row-template" data-bind="source: products">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Units</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name">
        </td>
        <td>
            #: kendo.toString(get("price"), "C") #
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: unitsInStock"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
</div>
```